# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product

I'm new in Magento.
I try to set up a configurable product by using this link

**https://popatkaran.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/create-configurable-products-programatically-magento/**

but when I try to run the file, I get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Configurable.php:284
>   Stack trace: #0

can someone help me, please?
thanks!